# Yeoman: overriding `app` location

Tags: yeoman

I'm using yeoman, bower, nmp and grunt for my angular project. Basically I'm going to replace default `app` location with `_attachments`. I've done this change inside Gruntfile.js

```
Gruntfile.js:      app: require('./bower.json').appPath || '_attachments'
```

However, when I'm creating controllers, views with yeoman e.g. `yo angular:controller xxx` it still creates inside `app` directory. How to override that?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular#output) in generator-angular's document, you can add `appPath` option to `bower.json` like followings.

```
{
  ...
  "appPath": "_attachments"
}
```

This option is loaded at the code below in generator-angular's [script-base.js](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/master/script-base.js).

```
     this.env.options.appPath = require(path.join(process.cwd(), 'bower.json')).appPath;
```

`this.env.options.appPath` is used in `Generator.prototype.appTemplate()` function to specify output directory.

```
 Generator.prototype.appTemplate = function (src, dest) {
   yeoman.generators.Base.prototype.template.apply(this, [
     src + this.scriptSuffix,
     path.join(this.env.options.appPath, dest.toLowerCase()) + this.scriptSuffix
   ]);
 };
```

I also verified that `appPath` in `bower.json` works for me as expected.

Comment: Does not work. Still wants to write into `app` directory. I doubt yeoman cares about bower.json

Comment: I added more information from generator-angular's source code which I double-checked yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather old question but I believe what you are looking for is in .yo-rc.json in your project directory.  There you can set the directories in which various items are created by yeoman.